# Is it possible to input VSCode a map [IDs, Strings] inside a .nativs file and output associated string while debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, natvis

I have lot of register IDs in the application, in order to debug the application I need to know the names of the registers not just the IDs.

Is it possible to maintain a map in .natvis file and use pretty print to convert IDs to register names (strings)?

Example: 0x1234, "foo"
0x1122, "bar"

Comment: I don't think natvis files support embedded data in any way.  Have you tried building a map as a global or static class variable, and referencing it in your natvis file?

Comment: Do you mean that your program shall pretty print the string or the debugger? The first is not possible, the second might be. If you have some struct with such an ID you could write a natvis that shows a string instead of the ID or additional to the ID. An even simpler solution would be not to use `int` for the register IDs but to use an enum, probably a scoped enum (enum class). The debugger can then, even without natvis, display the name of the value. If you need more help it would be good to see a short code snippet.